# Python higher order functions on lists

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I have the following list:

```
bananas = ['7,2,1 : Banana', 'Z : Banana', 'L,D : Banana']
```

I am would like to use Python's high order functions to derive the following:

```
[['7', '2', '1'], ['Z'], ['L', 'D']]
```

I have written this:

```
bananas_stripped = map(lambda x: [x.split(':')[0]], bananas)
```

...which produces this:

```
[['7,2,1 '], ['Z '], ['L,D ']]
```

I can apply another HOF like so:

```
test = map(lambda x: x[0].split(','), bananas_stripped)
```

But I can't figure out how to write it all in one function, i.e. I would like to do it all within `bananas_stripped`.

Comment: How about `map(lambda x: x.split(':')[0].strip().split(','), bananas)`?

Comment: @vaultah yep, that's great. Thanks a lot. Thanks for the strip() too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making vaultah's answer into a proper answer.

`map(lambda x: x.split(':')[0].strip().split(','), bananas)`

Comment: Hehe free reputation!

Answer (score 0):

```
bananas_stripped = [['7,2,1 '], ['Z '], ['L,D ']]
new_bananas_stripped = []
for item in bananas_stripped:
    item_string = item[0].replace(" ", "")
    item_string = item_string.split(',')
    new_bananas_stripped.append(item_string)
print(new_bananas_stripped)
```

And this will give the output

```
[['7', '2', '1'], ['Z'], ['L', 'D']]
```

Sorry i'm not so good at simplifying the code down into one line.

Comment: `item[0].replace("'", "")` is *completely* redundant.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
bananas_stripped = map(lambda x: [x.strip().split(",") for x in [x.split(':')[0]]], bananas)
```

Comment: Err, any reason for `for x in [x.split(':')[0]]`? Your solution doesn't produce the expected output.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.